# How can I use environment variables in body of a curl PUT request?

Tags: linux, curl, environment-variables

I want to do a curl request which uses environment variables in the body:

```
curl -XPUT http://${HOST}/create -d'{"user":"${USER}"}'
```

In this request, `${HOST}` is correctly replaced by the environment variable, but `${USER}` is not. How can I replace `${USER}` as well?

Comment: If you want your shell to expand `$USER`, it mustn't be inside single quotes.  Try `-d'{"user":"'"${USER}"'"}'`, but be very careful if `$USER` is from an untrusted source (or could otherwise contain `"` etc.).

Comment: Thank you, I am testing it right now! Would `-d'{"user":"'${USER}'"}'` also work? I am trying to understand why you added the extra `"`.

Comment: Maybe - I recommend always using double-quotes to enclose parameter expansions except when you definitely want word-splitting to happen on the result.  Even if I completely trust `$USER`, using the double-quotes helps signal what I expect.

Comment: Alternative: `-d"{\"user\":\"${USER}\"}"`

Comment: I will have to read on that, as I don't really understand what you meant with "except when you definitely want word-splitting to happen on the result". That said, if you paste your first comment in a separate answer, I could accept it as answer, as it worked! Thank you, appreciated.

Comment: The double quotes make the shell treat `"$USER"` as a single token, even if `$USER` contains spaces.  Without the quotes, one could set `USER='foo bar'` and you'd have two arguments where you expected one.

Comment: Oh, right! I forgot about that. Thanks for explaining that also Toby.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Shell parameter expansion doesn't take place within single quotes.  You can close the single quotes and start new double-quotes for the expansion:

```sh
curl -XPUT http://${HOST}/create -d'{"user":"'"${USER}"'"}'
```

Or you could use double-quotes instead:

```sh
curl -XPUT http://${HOST}/create -d"{\"user\":\"${USER}\"}"
```

In both cases, you need to be able to trust that `$USER` doesn't contain `"` - you might want to sanitize it first:

```sh
# This is a Bash extension to POSIX
USER=${USER//\"}
```